# ElectronJS rerequests an SVG sprite every time it's used, doesn't cache

Tags: svg, caching, electron, vite, svg-sprite

I have a Vite/React app that uses [@tabler/icons](https://tabler-icons.io/) for icons in the app, as well as letting the user choose icons for their own notes, so I need to be able to load them dynamically (instead of using the pre-made Tabler React components).

I'm including the entire SVG sprite in the application and referencing it like this:

```
export function Icon(props: {icon: string}) {
    return (
        <svg>
            <use href={"assets/tabler-sprite-nostroke.svg#tabler-" + props.icon} />
        </svg>
    );
}
```

This works fine when the Vite app is running on its own, the browser only requests the SVG sprite once, and all of the icons load instantly. This works in **both** the Vite dev server, and when the standalone vite app is built for production and served.

[image]

But when I bring that same Vite app into Electron and build it for production, anytime icons need to be rendered it takes ~300ms to load each icon individually, and if I check the Network tab I can see it's requesting the `tabler-sprite-nostroke.svg` file from the disk for every single icon being rendered.

[image: Network tab of Electron instance]

### What I've Tried

1. Putting the `tabler-sprite-nostroke.svg` file in the `public` folder in the vite app
2. Including the sprite file in the bundle using `vite-plugin-static-copy`
3. Importing the sprite from `node_modules` (https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html) (currently using, does the same as #1 and #2)
4. Disabling electron-builder putting the app into an asar archive
5. Manually injecting cache options into the Response Headers using `onHeadersReceived` in the Electron main process
6. Including the sprite as an `<img>` in the body to hopefully make Electron cache it
7. Using `xlinkHref` instead of `href` in the svg's `<use>` element

None of these have had any effect so far

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?

Comment: @deLiz I ended up using the Tabler Icons webfont package and that fixed the issue